# LinkedIn not picking up og:image from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I have a word press website, and when I share a blog on social media, all social media pulls up the thumbnails except Linkedin.

I have used the open graph tags perfectly. What could be wrong?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><meta property="og:description" content="<?php the_content();?>" /><meta property="og:type" content="post" /><meta property="og:image" content="https://www.intellectyx.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Analytics-400x225.jpg" />
```

Comment: when trying to access to your image link: "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074069/why-is-the-linkedin-apis-picture-urlsoriginal-field-no-longer-returning-v

Comment: Hi kaddath,Thats a sample url. even if i use valid url linedin is not showing image